# Difference b/w Symmetric and Reciprocal Networks

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, network, s-parameters

A circuit exhibits symmetry when interchanging ports across a plane of symmetry results in no change in the impedance, admittance or scattering parameters of the circuit.

Reciprocity also means reversing the ports. Is this not an operation belonging to the group of symmetry operations?

I also read somewhere that the property of reciprocity is independent of symmetry. How so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reciprocal network does indeed have a a symmetric S-matrix i.e. [S]=[S]^T.

I think confusion often arises here because reciprocity means that the transmission of a signal between any two ports does not depend on the direction of propagation. For the example of a 2-port network this implies only that S12=S21. It does NOT imply S11=S22, so in that sense the network is not identical looking in at each port. That is a more intuitive use of the word symmetric, which people may often use in conversation, hence the confusion.